# Symfony/Doctrine Infinite recursion while fetching from database with inverted side of a ManyToOne relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

## Context

In a simple Symfony project, I've created two entities, `Product` and `Category`, which are related by a `@ManyToOne` and a `@OneToMany` relationship with Doctrine Annotations. One category can have multiple products and one product relates to one category. I've manually inserted data in the `Category` table.

When I fetch data using `Category` entity repository and I display it with a `var_dump(...)`, an infinite recursion happens. When I return a JSON response with these data, it is just empty. It should retrieve exactly the data I inserted manually.

Do you have any idea of how to avoid this error without removing the inverse side relationship in the `Category` entity?

## What I've tried

- Adding the Doctrine Annotation [fetch="LAZY"](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytoone) in one side, the other side and both side of the relationship.
- Inserting `Category` object in the database using Doctrine to see if the database connection is working. Yes it is.
- Removing the [inverse side](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#setting-information-from-the-inverse-side) of the relationship. It worked but it's not what I want.

## Code snippet

**Controller**

```
dummy/src/Controller/DefaultController.php

...

$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Category::class);

// ===== PROBLEM HERE =====
//var_dump($repository->findOneByName('house'));
//return $this->json($repository->findOneByName('house'));

...
```

**Entities**

```
dummy/src/Entity/Category.php

<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\CategoryRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CategoryRepository::class)
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Product::class, mappedBy="category", fetch="LAZY")
     */
    private $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Product[]
     */
    public function getProducts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    public function addProduct(Product $product): self
    {
        if (!$this->products->contains($product)) {
            $this->products[] = $product;
            $product->setCategory($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProduct(Product $product): self
    {
        if ($this->products->contains($product)) {
            $this->products->removeElement($product);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($product->getCategory() === $this) {
                $product->setCategory(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```
dummy/src/Entity/Product.php

<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ProductRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductRepository::class)
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Category::class, inversedBy="products", fetch="LAZY")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $category;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategory(): ?Category
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setCategory(?Category $category): self
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you use `var_dump` for debugging purposes. For debugging purposes use `dump` or `dd` which is from `symfony/debug` and should already be enabled on `dev` by default. Both `dump` and `dd` *should* abort the infinite recursion in time. (Lots of symfony/doctrine objects/services have circular references or just *a lot* of referenced objects.) `dump` adds the given php var(s) to either the profiler (target mark symbol in the profiler bar) or to the output. `dd` adds the given var(s) like `dump` but also *ends* the process (so **d**ump and **d**ie). - On production never use dump/dd/var_dump, but properly serialize your data.

Secondly, `$this->json` is essentially a shortcut for packing `json_encode` into a `JsonResponse` object (or use the symfony/serializer instead). `json_encode` on the other hand serializes *public properties* of the object(s) given *unless* the object(s) implement [`JsonSerializable`](https://php.net/JsonSerializable) (see below). Since almost all entities usually have all their properties private, the result is usually an empty object(s) serialization.

There are a multitude of options to choose from, but essentially you need to solve the problem of infinite recursion. The imho standard options are:

- using the [symfony serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#usage) which can [handle circular references](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-circular-references) (which cause the infinite recursion/loop) and thus turning the object into a *safe* array. However, the results may still not be to your liking...
- implementing [`JsonSerializable`](https://php.net/JsonSerializable) on your entity and carefully avoid recursively adding the child-objects.
- building a *safe* array yourself from the object, to pass to `$this->json` ("the manual approach").

A *safe* array in this context is one, that contains only strings, numbers and (nested) arrays of strings and numbers, which essentially means, losing all actual objects.

There are probably other options, but I find these the most convenient ones. I usually prefer the `JsonSerializable` option, but it's a matter of taste. One example for this would be:

```
class Category implements \JsonSerializable { // <-- new implements!
   // ... your entity stuff
 
   public function jsonSerialize() {
       return [
           'id' => $this->id,
           'name' => $this->name,
           'products' => $this->products->map(function(Product $product) {
               return [
                   'id' => $product->getId(),
                   'name' => $product->getName(),
                   // purposefully excluding category here!
               ];
           })->toArray(),
       ];
   }
}
```

After adding this your code should just work. For dev, you always should use `dump` as mentioned and all `$this->json` will just work. That's why I usually prefer this option. However, the caveat: You only can have *one* json serialization scheme for categories this way. For any additional ways, you would have to use other options then ... which is almost always true anyway.